# TypeScript Transformers: Transform imported file

Tags: typescript, rollup, typescript-compiler-api

Is there a way for a TypeScript transformer to modify an imported file that is not a "SourceFile"?

For example in this repl: https://repl.it/@AndrewLeedham56/rollup-plugin-ts-external-repro#transformer.js (using @wessberg/rollup-plugin-ts) I am trying to add a React like import to each file, but `Child.tsx` is treated as `external` so they are not included in the outputted bundle. The problem here is that my visitor is only traversing SourceFile's and `Child.tsx` is not a SourceFile. So I am wondering if there is a way to traverse and modify imported files?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.